Environment to change the font size to a certain value
I am looking to create an environment that sets the font size to a certain value (say 12pt, with 53pt of baselineskip for this example, goal is to later be able to pass them as arguments, but for now I am making this the simplest possible to find the error)
Currently I have the following
\usepackage{fifo-stack}

\makeatletter
\FSCreate{setfs@oldfontsize}{\f@size}
\FSCreate{setfs@oldbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}


\newenvironment{setfs}{%
\FSPush{setfs@oldfontsize}{\f@size}
\FSPush{setfs@oldbaselineskip}{\the\baselineskip}
\fontsize{12pt}{53pt}\selectfont
}{%
\FSShowTop{setfs@oldfontsize}
\FSShowTop{setfs@oldbaselineskip}
\fontsize{\FSPop{hiddentext@oldfontsize}pt}{\FSPop{hiddentext@oldbaselineskip}}
}

\makeatother

Currently I get a weird error:
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
l. 137 \end{setfs}

The show statements give
The top of hiddentext@oldfontsize: 10.95
The top of hiddentext@oldbaselineskip: 13.6pt

I'm having trouble finding out why the unit would be missing. I thought I needed to add pt after the font size, but it did not help.

You can't put \makeatletter/\makeatother within the arguments of macros. Put your entire definition between them.

Hi! A curiosity: why don't you use grouping to go back to the old font settings? I mean, is there a specific reason for the push/pop thing?

The bad positioning of \makeatletter and \makeatother can be easily fixed. But this question lacks an example of usage, so it's impossible to test what you have in mind. Please, make a complete MWE

@Rmano because I am not aware of what grouping is… I am a bit new to the arcanes of tex/latex

@campa thank you for the info, I am new to these, so I wasn't completely sure about the usage - corrected it

Is not enough just an environment with \fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont ?
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}
\usepackage{dejavu,xcolor}
\newenvironment{fsize}[2]{\par\fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont\color{blue}}{\par} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{fsize}{14}{18}  \lipsum[1][1-2] \end{fsize} 
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{fsize}{8}{18}  \lipsum[1][1-2] \end{fsize} 
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{fsize}{22}{34}  \lipsum[1][1] \end{fsize} 
\end{document}



why does this work though? how does the font get set back to what it used to be before the environment was set? In particular, will it break if nested?

@tbrugere Like the color blue, the scope of many commands is limited when is whihtin a group or environment. There are no need to restore to black color not the font size. Just compare   \em  foo {foo} foo ...  that make all following text in cursive,  with is not the same with  foo {\em foo} foo ...

And no, in nested environments the same apply. When a child environment  end, font size return automatically to the parent environment.
